# Google Native Client - How to protect the source code?

Tags: google-nativeclient

With Google Native Client, can the source code be protected so that, unlike JavaScript, it is not visible in the client?

If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As the name says, Google Native Client uses native code.
That means, your code is compiled, just like with your average executable binary on the desktop. It can be disassembled, but the source code can't be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Native client means that you are running native code on the client.  In most cases, you'll be running i386 or amd64 machine language on your client.  If you're using a compiled language, then your users cannot directly recover it.  Users could disassemble your software to recover some information about your code, but they cannot recover the original source code (unless it *is* assembly language).  Rewriting a piece of software from the disassembled binary is difficult, but given enough time, it can usually be done.  It really depends on how paranoid you are about the people using your code.

Answer (score 1):

Native Client's structural requirements to enable reliable disassembly so that it can perform static analysis can make some techniques for code obfuscation unusable.  These are often the same techniques used by malware to make malware analysis difficult, i.e., have two valid interpretations of the instruction stream if decoded by different offsets.  Native Client does, however, permit a form of self-modifying code since it has JIT support.  Mono uses just-in-time code generation, for example, and the same interfaces can be used to create obfuscated code, as long as the JIT'ted code continue to conform to the NaCl security requirements.

Using the JIT interface would of course make your code non-portable to other CPU architectures.